# Horizontally Scroll-able Tabs inside a Fragment in an Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I need to implement Horizontally Scrollable Tabs inside a `Fragment` inside an already created `Activity`. But the `Inventory` class naturally extends `Fragment` and if I try to extend `FragmentActivity` from `Inventory`, it doesn't work.

Inside this:
[image]

Put something like this:
[image]

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Inventory extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inventory);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
    }
}



class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        if (position==0){
            fragment = new Fa();
        }
        if (position==1){
            fragment = new Fb();
        }
        if (position==2){
            fragment = new Fc();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Also, I am using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYjgX-GNRGo) to implement tabs.

Comment: why are you returning getCount() as 0? Shouldnt this be the number of tabs you wish to display in the first place?

Comment: yea thanks, but I have already solved my original question.